# Align title of a legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am trying to change the alignment of a legend title in ggplot. Specifically, I would like to put the title of a horizontal legend above the legend keys instead of on the left (default). It seems like I should be able to use `theme(legend.title.align)`, however that function does not seem to have any effect. I even tried using it for the default vertically-aligned right legend with no success.

Example below using `mtcars`

```
# Horizontal legend placed below plot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
 geom_point() +
 theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
       legend.direction = 'horizontal')

# Vertical legend right of plot with attempt at right alignment
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position = 'right',
  legend.direction = 'vertical', 
  legend.title.align = '1')
```

Is there a way to change the position of the legend.title in ggplot, particularly for placing the title above a horizontal legend?

Answer (score 0):

`guides(color = guide_legend(title.position = 'top')` solved my problem. I guess you just can't adjust title alignment within `theme()`